# deterministically recursively iterate over directory structure

Tags: recursion, filesystems

I have a static directory structure as input. My program starts from the root and recursively iterates through and lists the file names as output. My question is whether the ordering of the output list of filenames stays constant across multiple runs of my program. I have empirically observed that it does remain constant. But is it something that the programming language (lets say, java) or the operating system (I am using linux) guarantees.

Comment: When I mentioned static directory structure what I am using is a container that has been created as a snapshot of someone's laptop and mounted as a read-only on a different machine. So it doesn't change between runs. I am open to using ext2 if that guarantees deterministic listing of files between runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a couple things:

1. What method you're using the read the directories (`ls` sorts alphabetically, `readdir()` grabs in directory order)
2. Whether filenames are being created/deleted between runs.  This tends to screw you up for any filesystem.
3. What filesystem you're using (by default, `ext2` would give you a stable order.  `ext4`, which comes with directory hashing out of the box, will not).

In general, there is no guarantee that the order of directory entries will be stable between runs. If order is important, it's best to sort the directory after reading it.